# Angular: searcher(filters) working different depending on data type

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Let's do it quickly, I have 2 examples here that I want you to see and tell me why one is working and the other one isn't.

this is the one with a real json that I just extract from my app, this is the one not working: http://plnkr.co/edit/2Z5SMlANCGd3r4Trfwzm?p=preview

and I have this one which is working properly but with no real json: http://plnkr.co/edit/su8CD9L01XMXowCkXcel?p=preview

now, if you are able to see the error, the behavior that I want to achieve is the one on the 2nd Plunkr, everything is correct on that one, but I do not have a clue why the 1st one with the real information is not working.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query" />
    <div ng-repeat="sport in sports | filter:{$: query}" ng-show="sport.leagues.length">
      <div>
        <strong>{{sport.name}}</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-button-right" ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues" on-tap="goToLines(league)">
      {{league.name}}
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the data structure in the first example is "real"? The brackets (`[ ]`) don't seem to belong here.

Comment: as I mentioned to @Pedro Affonso below, I extract that info from Network in the browser console, I already removed the ```[]``` but the search box is not doing what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The  `$scope.sports` array is not in the same structure.

In #1 you have:

```
[{
    "0": {
        "name": "Basketball",
        "leagues": {[
...
```

In #2 you have:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Basketball",
        "leagues": [{
...
```

so your statement `ng-show="sport.leagues.length"` will not work in #1.

Either adjust the `ng-show` or remove the indexes from the `$scope.sports` array and build it like #2.

Comment: sorry but I did not get you

Answer (score 0):

You have to change two lines.

```
Line 5:  $scope.sports = {
Line 298: };
```

Removing the [] bracketssolves your problem. Because in the case that doesn't work, you have something resembling an array inside another array (actually it is an object but that's not important in this case).

Comment: Actually is real, I extract that info from Network in browser console. I already removed those lines and the info is showing properly BUT is not doing what I want, I need that the searcher looks for the information as in the 2nd example. @Pedro Affonso

Answer (score 0):

The filter filter works only on arrays. Your first data structure is not an array.

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

> Selects a subset of items from [array] and returns it as a new array

Where [array] is of the type Array. As already noted in the comments the data structure seems strange, with or without the additional brackets.

### Update

If you want to convert the structure into an array on the client side you can do the following:

```
var newArray = [];
for (var key in $scope.sports) {
  newArray.push($scope.sports[key]);
}
$scope.sports = newArray;
```

Comment: and how can I turn my abject into an array?